# Looping through a column to move cells with font size 10 down one row

Tags: vba, excel

I have section title cells set at 10 pt font while all other data is set at 9 point font in column A.  I am trying to write a vba macro to loop through column A to move each title cell down one row(because the csv leaves a blank cell below them) then move on to the next title cell in the column.  Here is my attempt but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
Sub FontSpacing()
    Dim Fnt As Range

  For Each Fnt In Range("A8:A5000")
      If Fnt.Font.Size = "10" Then
       ActiveCell.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(",1")
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub FontSpacing()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8:A5000")
        If r.Font.Size = 10 Then
            r.Offset(1,0).Value = r.Value
            r.Value = vbNullString
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

The issues:

- `Offset(",1")` shouldn't have the speech marks. I.e. it should be `Offset(0,1)`. In fact, if you want to paste to the *row* below, then it should be `Offset(1,0)`.
- Avoid using `ActiveCell`. It's not the cell that is looping through your range, it's just the cell that was active on the worksheet when you ran the sub.
- `Fnt` is a bad name for a range, it's probably the reason you got confused. When declaring (*dimensioning*) a range, try to give it a name that makes it clear you're working with a range.

Extra:

- Fully qualify your range reference to avoid an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet` e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`.
- Avoid cutting an pasting by setting the `Value` directly
- Your indentation is out, which makes it look like a complete Sub, but it's missing the `End Sub`.

Comment: That results in a run time error "13" -type mismatch

Comment: now it's running into a syntax error on the" r.Cut Destination:=r.Offset(1,)" line

Comment: @ParkerMcA I changed the code a bit already and just tested it - should all be working fine now

Comment: This is it! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you meant 1 Row below or 1 Column right so:
To shift 1 Column:

```
Sub FontSpacing()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A5000")
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Font.Size = "10" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
        cell.Clear
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

To shift 1 Row:

```
Sub FontSpacing()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A5000")
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Font.Size = "10" Then
        a = cell.Row + 1
        Rows(a & ":" & a).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=1
        cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = cell.Value
        cell.Offset(1, 0).Font.Size = "11"
        cell.Clear
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It was to shift the Cells with 10 pt font down one row.  The second sub seems close but it continues with that same cell bumping it continually down the row rather than skipping it after the movement then moving on to the next Title Cell along the column

Comment: Try again. Should work. And just for your record the moved ones will change the font from 10 to 11